# Android Service get a null pointer exception when installed as system app

Tags: android, service

I have a Launcher app with a service that runs as user app normally, But after I pused it into /system/app/ as a System app, It can NOT be installed, here are the strange logcat:

```
F/FileObserver(  367): Unhandled exception in FileObserver com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$AppDirObserver@41130430
F/FileObserver(  367): java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
F/FileObserver(  367):  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:150)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:124)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getDataPathForPackage(PackageManagerService.java:3579)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:3940)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.scanPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:3382)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$1700(PackageManagerService.java:172)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$AppDirObserver.onEvent(PackageManagerService.java:5541)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent(FileObserver.java:125)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
F/FileObserver(  367):  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:88)
D/dalvikvm(  367): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1488K, 25% free 11974K/15816K, paused 56ms, total 57ms
```

A String null pointer! What happened?

Here is the related Android source code from PackageManagerService (Android4.2):

```
private File getDataPathForPackage(String packageName, int userId) {
    /*
     * Until we fully support multiple users, return the directory we
     * previously would have. The PackageManagerTests will need to be
     * revised when this is changed back..
     */
    if (userId == 0) {
        return new File(mAppDataDir, packageName);
    } else {
        return new File(mUserAppDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + userId
            + File.separator + packageName);
    }
}
```

But I still don't know the reason.

UDPATE:

It is the reason of `<original-package>` tag in Manifest, Remove it and the problem gone.

Comment: It is "} else {" in my source code.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly your package name is coming as null. If you see the documentation of [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) you will notice that the exact exception is thrown when `name` part is `null`.

> public File (File dir, String name) 
>   Constructs a new file using the specified directory and name.
>
> Parameters 
>   dir   the directory where the file is stored. 
>   name  the file's name.
>
> Throws 
>   NullPointerException  if name is null.